# Wordpress Mostrar valor de un custom field en otro custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

estoy utilizando ACF para crear campos personalizados y mostrarlos en pantalla, tengo creados custom fields llamados local y visitante para el custom post type sp-event y estoy intentando mostrar el valor de estos campos dentro de una página de wp (page.php) editando un shortcode.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando

```
                            <?php 
                            $posts = get_field('relacion');
                            if( $posts ): ?>
                                <?php foreach( $posts as $p ): ?>
                                    <?php the_field('visitante', $p->ID); ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
```

este código muestra el valor del CPT "visitante" REPETIDO para cada elemento del custom post type cuando lo que busco es que muestre el valor de "visitante" asignado al custom post type en cuestión. El problema creo que esta en el bucle que puede que esté mal formado.

Alguna sugerencia

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, la solución fue utilizar `get_post_meta` para obtener el valor del custom field

Comment: Hola. Podrías extender tu respuesta indicando cómo usaste get_post_meta en tu código. Así, otros con el mismo problema podrán ver cómo se resuelve en el futuro :)

Comment: Hola @MarceloHerrera: Bienvenido a SOes. Por favor, como dice el compañero, añade más contexto a tu respuesta y hazla útil para otros usuarios que vengan en un futuro. Consulta [el siguiente enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

cambia

```
<?php the_field('visitante', $p->ID); ?>
```

por

```
<?php echo get_field('visitante', $p->ID); ?>
```